# Pixelated effect doesn't translate well on export on Gimp

Tags: gimp, pixelation

I've installed Gimp to do a very simple pixelated effect on images. Now, it IS satisfying in the Gimp interface, but whenever I export it to PNG, I get an ugly faux-pixel result. Any idea where this could be coming from? (It should be noted that I am a total neophyte in graphic design.)

The pixel effect was done by selecting the layer and then going into Filters > Blur > Pixelation. I have taken the original image from a [random website](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=fallout%2076%20logo&atb=v195-1&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fmedia.playstation.com%2Fis%2Fimage%2FSCEA%2Ffallout-76-white-4-color-logo-01-us-16oct18%3F%24native_t%24) and just copy-pasted the logo in a separate file, then applied the filter.

Here is a OneDrive link to the xcf file: [xcf file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApS4Tm_ns2cdhBUbg7ja-Q9D8-b9?e=Kdjp1t)

Here is an example in Gimp with the Fallout 76 logo:

[image: Good pixellation]

And here is the same image exported in PNG:

[image: Bad pixellation]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I can replicate the issue.  What is the image mode of the PNG? How did you make the pixel effect. What are your export settings? Perhaps consider sharing the XCF file. Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/137735/edit) and provide more information.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you - I added some info and a link to the xcf file, hopefully it is enough. I'm not sure where to check the image mode of the PNG? It should also be noted that exporting to jpg yields the same result. My interface is in French so I'm not sure the export settings would be very legible.

Comment: The XCF is in Indexed mode. Click Image > Mode > RGB. Then it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would have never found it by myself...

Comment: I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The XCF is in Indexed colour mode.

To fix it, click *Image > Mode > RGB*. Now when you export the PNG, it will work as expected.

When you open an image from the web in GIMP, especially PNG or GIF images, it's always good to check the image mode. Convert to RGB first before editing, especially if you intend to use filters or edit the colours of an image. Note also that many of the legacy filters won't work in Indexed colour mode.

The reason for this is that in Indexed colour, the number of colours is restricted to a limited palette of colours which could be anything from 256 to just 2 colours. To be able to edit the image properly it should be in RGB mode so the full range of colours is available.